# Actionscript 3 add video admob

Tags: actionscript-3, admob

I have downloaded milkmangames and configured google admob interstitial. But I want earn Money with VideoAD (video that you have to watch for 30sec),and I can't do this with google. So is there a Way to do this in actionscript 3 and milkman? There is some tutorial about it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from their website for the latest version of milkmans adMob ANE ($29.95)

"Milkman's simple and intuitive ActionScript API will have you showing banner, interstitial, or video ads in just a few lines of code"

So yes you should have a pdf with your download with step by step instructions, if you get stuck email them for fast free support.

If you didnt pay for it and found and old outdated version somewhere, then it may or may not support video at all